# Create new object from value of another object in js

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is really simple and there is a syntax error that I can't understand:

I have an array that contains some objects, and I want to create another array using some value of those objects:

```
let fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}]
let respone = []

// different implementation
fields.map(item => {
   respone.push({item.label: ''}) } )
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`


fields.map(item => {
   respone = [...response, {item.label: ''}]  } )
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`



fields.map(item => {
   respone = [...response, {item['label']: ''}]  } )
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`
```

and obviously the error is from creating the object `{item['label']: ''}`.
What is the reason for those errors, and what is the best way to create new objects from the existing object values.

Comment: Try `fields.map(({type, label}) => ({[label]: ''}))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have an array of objects, consisting of `type` and `label`. You want to make a "composite object" using that array. First thing, you don't want `respone` to be an array, you want it to be an object. Second, you want to name the key on `respone` to the value of `item.label`.

Try this code:

```js
let fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}]

// Create an empty object
let respone = {}

// Iterate over the fields array, using each one to set the  key and value
//  on our respone object.
fields.forEach(item => { respone[item.label] = item.type} );

// Let's see how it looks!
console.log(respone);
```

**Edit**: Based on a comment, it doesn't really make sense to use `.map()` -- the purpose of that is to return a new array, usually of transformed data, based on the array values. In this case, it makes more sense to use `Array.forEach(...)`, the code has been amended to this.

Comment: Why use `.map` ?

Comment: True, could just as easily have used any mechanism to loop over the array `fields`, `.forEach` would have worked just as well. Good catch, edited the post accordingly. Thank you.

Comment: Does `.map()` and `.forEach` do iteration in different way or `.forEach` is just nicer and more readble?

Comment: It's about intent. `.map()` is intended to return a new array of  the same length as the original, with the same or modified data. `.forEach()`, on the other hand, is intended to simply iterate over that array and do something at each iteration.

Answer (score 2):

Well the error is how you're trying to define key.

`item.label` this need to be changed to `[item.label]` as you want computed key (which needs to evaluated first and than used as key )

```js
let fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}]

let respone = []

fields.forEach(item => {
   respone.push({[item.label]: ''}) } )
   
console.log(respone)
```

> what's the difference between `item.label` and `[item.label]` ?

[item.label] will resolve item.label first and than use as key and it need not to be a valid identifier

item.label try to use it directly as key which is not correct JS identifier in this case

for reference [read here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Dot_notation)

Comment: what's the difference between `item.label` and `[item.label]`?

Comment: `[item.label]` will resolve `item.label` first and than use as key `item.label` try to use it directly as key which is not correct JS identifier in this case

Comment: And that's returning an array of named properties, not a compound object built from an array of  one-property objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to transform the array into another array with the same number of elements, then you want `map`:

```
let fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}]
let response = fields.map(field => ({[field.label]: ''}));
console.log(response);
```

The return from `map` is an array so you don't need to create and push to separate storage; `map` does that for you.

---

If you want to create a new object with members based on the array content,
`reduce` is what you want:

```
let fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}]
let response = fields.reduce((obj, field) => ({...obj, [field.label]: ''}), {});
console.log(response);
```

(If you don't mind the eslint warning, you can not create the temp objects during the `reduce`:)

```
let fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}]
let response = fields.reduce((obj, field) => {
    obj[field.label] = '';
    return obj;
}, {});
console.log(response);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because u r using a "variable" as an object key, you need to use a bracket to tell the browser this is a "variable", otherwise the browser will treat it as a string, but you can not use a "." in a key, so it throw an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .":

You should write like this:

```js
var fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}];
var respone = [];

fields.map(item => {
  respone.push({
    [item.label]: ''
  })
});

console.log(respone);
```

Or if you can't understand, this should help you to understand:

```js
var fields = [{type:'a',label:'email'},{type:'b',label:'name'},{type:'a',label:'tel'}];
var respone = [];

fields.map(item => {
  let obj = {};
  obj[item.label] = '';
  respone.push(obj);
});

console.log(respone);
```

Comment: You should use `forEach` (which returns nothing) instead of `map` (which returns a new array).